# Table flashing or color change

Tags: javascript

I have 3 column table, I will need one of the columns to give me color change notification or flashing, how to do this?

Comment: I changed you all uppercase, so that your question will not be immediately closed by irritated users. I think you have to add some more details about what you are doing, though.

Comment: ok i will explain more, lets say i have one table which contains 3 columns 1. Name, 2. Details 3. Remarks 
when i add in the remark field an important notice or important date i will need it to be flashing (flashing light or flashing color) when the time comes or as soon as i set it as important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a (rather annoying) simple JavaScript code snippet here that does this:

http://www.javascriptbank.com/flashing-background-color.html

You can make it less annoying by reducing the number of colors and increasing the delays :)

Note that you'll have to modify it from using the entire document to using just the element(s) that you want to change.  I'm guessing a bunch of td elements?

Comment: this is full background and it has many colors i need only flashing with one color and in one columns in the table

Comment: You can reduce the number of colors by just removing those lines in the code.  As for just the column, unless there's a way to reference a column in HTML with which I am unfamiliar (entirely possible) I imagine you could just set those td elements to all share a class descriptor and select elements based on that.

Comment: can you give me example for any one td ?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('test'); should get any elements that have a class "test" on them.  Put that class on the td elements in question and it'll find them.  You can also use jQuery selectors to put a little more logic into it.  Or you could select all the tr elements and loop through them selecting the nth td element in each one, etc.